# Pre-Emphasis of a signal

Tags: signal-processing

I'm trying to describe the process of Pre-Emphasis (of a signal) in my equations, but I don't know whether or not this makes sense.

$Y[n] = X[n] - 0.95 \cdot X[n-1]$

Where Y = pre-emphasis after, X = inputted signal

Given:-

$X = \begin{bmatrix}
0.95 & 0.85 \\ 
1.56 & 0.12 
\end{bmatrix}
$

$X = \begin{bmatrix}
(0.85 - 0.95 \cdot 0.95) & (0.85 - 0.95 \cdot 0.95) \\
(1.56 - 0.95 \cdot 0.85) & (0.12 - 0.95 \cdot 1.56)  
\end{bmatrix}$

Result:

$Y = \begin{bmatrix}
0.95 & -0.0525\\ 
1.60987 & 0.12
\end{bmatrix}$

I know the equation is right, but, for some reason the calculations don't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A signal $X[n]$ is usually represented as a row or column. I don't understand why $X$ is a matrix. What do the values represent?

Comment: @leonbloy Thank's for the reply. I just wanted to provide test data, in order to show the transformation (given X, after the calculations the resulting matrice would be Y)

Comment: Sorry, that didn't answer my question

Comment: @leonbloy So I am writing my thesis and I gave this equation, I want to show "test data" to show how if I have this matrix, I perform that particular calculation this is what the resulting matrix would be. Are you suggesting that these should not be as a matrix form? If so, how should I represent this

Comment: @leonbloy I get you now, it shouldn't be a matrice because `x[n]` is just a column. Thank you :)